# WPF user control with View Model

Tags: wpf, viewmodel

I created a my own user control wrappping a GridControl and defined some columns, so I can reuse this control in multiple places. I created a dependency property called AttachmentList in my user control to hold a list of strings I want to display in the grid.

```
<dxg:GridControl AutoGenerateColumns="None" EnableSmartColumnsGeneration="True" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AttachmentList, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I my parent window, I use

```
<vm:FileListGridControl AllowDrop="True"
                     AttachmentList="{Binding Path=Email.FileList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <vm:GridDragDropBehavior/>
                    </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
</vm:FileListGridControl>
```

Email.FileList is defined as ObservableCollection in my ViewModel. GridDragDropBehavior will call Email.FileList.Add() to add strings to Email.FileList. Problem is I can see strings have been added to FileList, but not shown in the GridControl.

I though use ObserableCollection and twoway binding should update the UI. What did I do wrong?

**Edit** Here are the defintions

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AttachmentListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AttachmentList", typeof(IList<FileWrapper>), typeof(FileListGridControl));

public IList<FileWrapper> AttachmentList
{
    get { return (IList<FileWrapper>)GetValue(AttachmentListProperty); }
    set { SetValue(AttachmentListProperty, value); }
}
```

In My Email class, I defined

```
ObservableCollection<FileWrapper> _FileList = new ObservableCollection<FileWrapper>();
public ObservableCollection<FileWrapper> FileList { get { return _FileList; } set { _FileList = value; } }
```

If I remove my control and add the GridControl directly in the Parent window, everything works as expected.

Comment: @Clemens I have updated my post. Regarding two-way binding, which mode should I use? I am drag and drop files into the GridControl, which will add the file names to the collection and it will notify the UI about the change.

Comment: What `Binding Mode` you use depends on *your* requirements. See the *Direction of the Data Flow* section of the [Data Binding Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx#basic_data_binding_concepts) page on MSDN for more information.

Comment: It is not necessary to set Mode or UpdateSourceTrigger at all. However, make sure that the DataContext property of your FileListGridControl is set to an instance of your view model class (which declares the `Email` property).

Comment: And why is `FileList` a read/write property? Is it actually set anywhere? If so, you would have to raise a property change notification, i.e. implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: @Clements ObservableCollection should notify the UI when anything is added/removed to the collection. I think my AttachmentList should be ObservableCollection instead of IList

Comment: @Clemens change to ObservableCollection doesn't work. FileList should have only get

Comment: It is sufficient to declare AttachmentList as `IList<FileWrapper>`. The important thing is that the actual collection object that is assigned to the property is an `ObservableCollection<FileWrapper>` (which implements the IList<T> interface). You have already bound it to a view model property that is an ObservableCollection, so that this shouldn't be your problem.